# Finding the shortest path between points to LineString PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have a `MultiPolygon`. Something like this:

[image]

All one colored circles make up one multipolygon. I would like to find the shortest line to connect all one colored polygons.

The first idea was to find all possible lines between one group of points. Then sort these lines by distance and point_id and loop over all points and keep the lowest distance line for each point and then use linemerge to make it one big line.

Expected result would be something like this:

[image]

Don't know if this idea would work and don't have any clue how to implement it in postgis. Any ideas?

Comment: This is really a routing problem, no?. Perhaps use pgRouting?

Comment: Maybe routing can help, I've never used it but I'll look into it. I need the linestring for display purposes not actual routing.

Comment: could traveling salesman solver be the answer? You need graph-table where you have all line combinations  between points...

Comment: See [TSP](http://pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/tsp.html) in pgRouting.